# Create 30 min slots from given date and time

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

**I have time in below format**

> 2015-10-28T18:37:04.899+05:30

**I have to create slots in below format**

> 11.00AM - 12.00PM 28/10/15
>
> 12.00PM - 1.00PM 28/10/15
>
> 1.00PM - 2.00PM 28/10/15

```
String timeValue = "2015-10-28T18:37:04.899+05:30";
        StringTokenizer  stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(timeValue,"T");
        String dateValue = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        String endDateValue = "2015-10-30";
        String restString= stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        StringTokenizer secondTokeniser = new StringTokenizer(restString,":");
        String hours = secondTokeniser.nextElement().toString();
        String minutes = secondTokeniser.nextElement().toString();
        hours = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(hours) + 2);
        if (Integer.parseInt(minutes) > 30){
            minutes = "00";
        }else{
            minutes = "30";
        }

        String amOrPm = null;
        if(Integer.parseInt(hours) < 12){
            amOrPm = "AM";
        }else{
            amOrPm = "PM";
            hours = String.valueOf(getHoursValue(Integer.parseInt(hours)));
        }
        String time1 = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + amOrPm;
        String time2 = "12" + ":" + "00" + " AM ";
        String format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm a";


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        try {
            Date dateObj1 = sdf.parse(dateValue + " " + time1);
            Date dateObj2 = sdf.parse(endDateValue + " " + time2);
            Logger.d(TAG, "Date Start: " + dateObj1);
            Logger.d(TAG, "Date End: " + dateObj2);
            long dif = dateObj1.getTime();
            while (dif < dateObj2.getTime()) {
                Date slot = new Date(dif);
                Log.d(TAG, "Hour slot = " + slot);
                dif += 1800000;
            }
        }catch (ParseException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**By the above code I am getting below output**

> Wed Jan 28 20:00:00 IST 2015
>
> Wed Jan 28 20:30:00 IST 2015
>
> Wed Jan 28 21:00:00 IST 2015
>
> Wed Jan 28 21:30:00 IST 2015
>
> Wed Jan 28 22:00:00 IST 2015
>
> Wed Jan 28 22:30:00 IST 2015
>
> which is in 24 hours format

**I want the below out put format**

> 11.00AM - 12.00PM 28/10/15
>
> 12.00PM - 1.00PM 28/10/15
>
> 1.00PM - 2.00PM 28/10/15

Can any one please help me regarding this

Comment: I really do not understand the point of downvote , it became a trend here

Comment: maybe just bad people who downvote without leaving a reason

Comment: yeah I guess they enjoy bro

Comment: Is there any specific login to create desired output !! means any datetime would have same time slot irrespective of date

Comment: @MiteshParmar , No there is nothing specific login. yeah it will have same time slot for next 1 day

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how your output depend on input? You just take day and create these three slots?

Comment: @skywall-   the use case is I get the server time which always gives today's times , lets say 2.15 PM  7 NOV 2015 I received from server, now I have to create slots from 4.30 PM 7 NOV 2015 to 12.00 AM 9 NOV 2015  each slot of 30 min ,  - for example 4.30 - 5.00 7 NOV 2015, 5.00 - 5.30 7 NOV 2015 and so on till 11.30 PM - 12.00 AM 8 NOV 2015 next day mid night ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, please note that for month you shoud use `MM` instead of `mm`. I add a simple `getHoursValue` since I don't know yours.

Hope this helps!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        displayTimeSlots();
    }

    private int getHoursValue(int hours){
        return hours - 12;
    }

    private void displayTimeSlots(){
        String timeValue = "2015-10-28T18:37:04.899+05:30";
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(timeValue,"T");
        String dateValue = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        String endDateValue = "2015-10-30";
        String restString= stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        StringTokenizer secondTokeniser = new StringTokenizer(restString,":");
        String hours = secondTokeniser.nextElement().toString();
        String minutes = secondTokeniser.nextElement().toString();
        hours = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(hours) + 2);
        if (Integer.parseInt(minutes) > 30){
            minutes = "00";
        }else{
            minutes = "30";
        }

        String amOrPm;
        if(Integer.parseInt(hours) < 12){
            amOrPm = "AM";
        }else{
            amOrPm = "PM";
            hours = String.valueOf(getHoursValue(Integer.parseInt(hours)));
        }
        String time1 = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + amOrPm;
        String time2 = "12" + ":" + "00" + " AM ";
        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        try {
            Date dateObj1 = sdf.parse(dateValue + " " + time1);
            Date dateObj2 = sdf.parse(endDateValue + " " + time2);
            Log.d("TAG", "Date Start: " + dateObj1);
            Log.d("TAG", "Date End: " + dateObj2);
            long dif = dateObj1.getTime();
            while (dif < dateObj2.getTime()) {
                Date slot1 = new Date(dif);
                dif += 3600000;
                Date slot2 = new Date(dif);
                dif += 3600000;
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a, dd/MM/yy");
                Log.d("TAG", "Hour slot = " + sdf1.format(slot1) + " - " + sdf2.format(slot2));
            }
        }catch (ParseException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Date Start: Wed Oct 28 20:00:00 GMT+07:00 2015
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Date End: Fri Oct 30 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2015
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 08:00 PM - 09:00 PM, 28/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 10:00 PM - 11:00 PM, 28/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 12:00 AM - 01:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 02:00 AM - 03:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 04:00 AM - 05:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 06:00 AM - 07:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.506 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 08:00 AM - 09:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.527 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.537 24299-24299/? D/TAG: Hour slot = 12:00 PM - 01:00 PM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.537 24299-24299/com.example.timeslots D/TAG: Hour slot = 02:00 PM - 03:00 PM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.556 24299-24299/com.example.timeslots D/TAG: Hour slot = 04:00 PM - 05:00 PM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.566 24299-24299/com.example.timeslots D/TAG: Hour slot = 06:00 PM - 07:00 PM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.566 24299-24299/com.example.timeslots D/TAG: Hour slot = 08:00 PM - 09:00 PM, 29/10/15
11-07 14:54:02.566 24299-24299/com.example.timeslots D/TAG: Hour slot = 10:00 PM - 11:00 PM, 29/10/15
```

Comment: You're welcome, you should test before accept. However, your question title `Create 30 min slots`, question body `1-hour slots`. So, if you want 30-min, you can replace `3600000` with `1800000` :)

Comment: yeah I will replace with 180000 . Thank you again Sir

Comment: But apart from using our own logic skywall has given a very appropriate answer using Calendar, sorry but I can give bounty to only one guy

Comment: I see, don't worry about the bounty, I just want to make sure that my answer works for your issue or not. The original code is yours, I just check and modify it to work well :)

Comment: Yeah thats true. I am so sorry

Answer (score 10):

I think, this is something you are looking for:

```
String timeValue = "2015-10-28T18:37:04.899+05:30";
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(timeValue));

    if (startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30) {
        startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    } else {
        startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // overstep hour and clear minutes
        startCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendar.setTime(startCalendar.getTime());

    // if you want dates for whole next day, uncomment next line
    //endCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    endCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24 - startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    endCalendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

    SimpleDateFormat slotTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
    SimpleDateFormat slotDate = new SimpleDateFormat(", dd/MM/yy");
    while (endCalendar.after(startCalendar)) {
        String slotStartTime = slotTime.format(startCalendar.getTime());
        String slotStartDate = slotDate.format(startCalendar.getTime());

        startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        String slotEndTime = slotTime.format(startCalendar.getTime());

        Log.d("DATE", slotStartTime + " - " + slotEndTime + slotStartDate);
    }

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // date in wrong format
}
```

I need to mention, this code ignore time zone, but it seems you don't need it. Example output:

```
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 07:00PM - 07:30PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 07:30PM - 08:00PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 08:00PM - 08:30PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 08:30PM - 09:00PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 09:00PM - 09:30PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 09:30PM - 10:00PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 10:00PM - 10:30PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 10:30PM - 11:00PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 11:00PM - 11:30PM, 28/10/15
cz.skywall.stack D/DATE: 11:30PM - 12:00AM, 28/10/15
```

As I mentioned in code, you can generate slots for whole next day by uncommenting line `endCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);`.

Comment: your solution looks neat and clean as compared to others , will accept once I will test the code . Thank you so much for answer

Comment: perfect answer for all the scenario , I have tested this code for all scenario including 31 DEC 2015 and end of the month and end of the year , it works beautifully , I did some tweak to full fill my requirement , thanks a lot

Comment: Its generating time slots perfectly. But I have small problem I want to generate slots from 12AM to 11 PM on same day but its starting from 12:30AM. by this input "2016-11-03 00:00:00".

Comment: @Shyam Removing first `if (startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30) { ... }` statement should tend to requested behavior.

Comment: I got an another answer which was perfect for my requirement. Thanks @skywall for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your first time interval and similar you can find other your two remaining time interval.

```
String time ="2015-10-28T18:37:04.899+05:30";

        try {
        Date d= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(time);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa dd/MM/yy");
        String date =dateFormat1.format( d);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dateFormat1.parse(date));
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

        String one=dateFormat1.format(calendar.getTime());
        String[] strings=date.split(" ");
        one=(strings[0]+strings[1]+"-"+one);

        System.out.println("Time here "+one);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="rotu">hello</div>

<script>
    var r = document.getElementById('rotu');
    for(let i=8;i<22;i++){
        if(i.toString().length === 1){
            i = '0'+i;
        }
        r.innerHTML += '<div>'+i+':00</div><div>'+i+':30</div>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful